# Unique and id is getting null in Moongose update/upsert

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have one schema like this:

```
export const HotelSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  firstName: String,
  email: { type: String, unique: true },
  canLogin: Boolean
},
  {
    collection: "hotels"
  }
);
```

and to add/update I am using this query:

```
this.hotelModel.updateOne({ _id: hotel._id }, hotel, { upsert: true });
```

Where hotel object I am passing:

```
{
 "email" : "er.markar@gmail.com",
 "name" : "sunny123"
}
```

But it is inserting duplicate emails with `_id` as null:

Even I tried `findOneAndUpdate`. tried `autoIndex` in the email schema. Still not working.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

See https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html#the-unique-option-is-not-a-validator

Infact, you should use unique index on a field. That works!

Answer (score 0):

You are passing email and name, but you are not passing "*_id*", so "*hotel._id*" will not be found. Instead you should do as follows:

```
this.hotelModel.updateOne({ email:hotel.email}, hotel, { upsert:true});
```